# Issue with image not loading in ionic4 app

Tags: html, ionic4

[image]

I have been trying to load image in ionic-html page but the image isn't loading on the page, here I have written the tag , also tried using giving the full path of the image and with , but as soon as I give the tag , the whole page itself isn't loading. Here is the code for ionic-html page.

[image]

Comment: check the build error i guess path is not correct

Comment: what build error?

Comment: how did you run the application ?check the console

Comment: Checked the build console but there's no error there, its compiled succesfully, run the application by ionic serve.

Comment: reposted the the image for the build console for the reference

Comment: check the web console network ab you will see a error 404 for that image .check the path and correct

Comment: any errors in browser console ?

Comment: no errors in the browser console

Comment: The error on browser console - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). "But the path is correct"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post code as images or even worse include links to screenshots of code. people generally don't follow those links. Instead use proper code formatting tags to post/add code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on more information how to ask a proper question.

Comment: add folder name before image. i.e. src='assets/id.png' .

Answer (score 0):

For images and other media stuff there is a folder named "assets" in "src" folder. You need to put your image in assets folder and you need to write -

```
<img src="assets/id.png" alt="image">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it did worked image was already in the assets folder, just added the assets path in the src tag.